# Rails FileUtils and File.rename keep deleteing files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fileutils

I'm  trying to iterate through a directory of image files and rename them. Each time I run this method it will rename one file and delete the rest. I also used File.rename.

```
require 'fileutils'

def rename_image_files
    @last_product = Product.find(:last).id + 1

    Dir.foreach("app/assets/images/products/#{@last_product}").each do |item|
    @count = 0
    @count += 1

    new_name = "#{@last_product.to_s << '_'}#{@count}"
    @item = item
    unless @item == '.' or @item == '..'


    FileUtils.mv("app/assets/images/products/#{@last_product}/#{@item}", "app/assets/images/products/#{@last_product}/#{new_name}.png")


    end
end
```

Comment: You shoud initialize `@count = 0` before the loop

Comment: `new_name = "#{@last_product.to_s << '_'}#{@count}"` should be `new_name = "#{@last_product}_#{@count}"`